# Code block Prettify for Code Review after graduation

Tags: support, design, syntax-highlighting, code-block

Some Code Review regulars have been discussing [on Code Review Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3732/42632) and [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18423715#18423715) the possibility of redesigning the look of code blocks as part of eventual "graduated" site design.

Would you please indicate if this can be done, and if that is the case, what steps we could take to start coming up with ideas and see what the Code Review community likes? Does Stack Exchange use the same CSS model as [the Google Prettify template](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/prettify.css)?

Answer (score 5):

According to this page, Stack Exchange [uses Google Prettify](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).  I do not have the information to know whether code blocks can be redesigned, but I doubt it.